# Perform speech recognition from a memory stream in a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, speech-recognition

I have speech recognition working well in my C# Windows Store App using the system audio recording device (microphone). I want to perform speech recognition from a file or memory stream.  How can I do this using the Bing speech recognition control for Windows Store apps?

Comment: So it seems to me like the speech recognizer just creates a tunnel to the Bing speech api and passes in the audio stream from the microphone to it, along with the credentials that you enter into it. I bet that you could use Fiddler to intercept the initial exchange (and location), then replicate that. I'm not sure if it will require any sort of private key from the extension library itself or not.

Comment: Did you get more info about underlaying REST query ? or a way to provide a MemoryStream ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeEncausse Unfortunately not.